# Scalar and cross product: perpendicularity and parallelism

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, inner-products, cross-product

### Preface:

**1.**  I have two straight line $r$ and $r'$, we know that

$$r: ax+by+c=0 \iff \mathbf{v}=(a,b)\perp r \tag 1$$
$$r: ax+by+c=0 \iff \mathbf{w}=(a',b')\perp r' \tag 2$$

If $r\parallel r'$ the coefficients, of $r'$, for example, are proportional to $r$, hence it must be

$$ \left|\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
a' & b'
\end{matrix}\right|=0 \iff ab'-a'b=0 \tag 3$$

If $r\perp r'$ must be

$$aa'+bb'=0 \tag 4$$

**2.** If $A\equiv(x_1,y_1)$ and $B\equiv(x_2,y_2)$ we know that $\overrightarrow{AB}=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)$.

**3.** If $\mathbf{v}=(a,b) \parallel \mathbf{w}=(h,k)$ then
$$ a=\lambda h, \quad b=\mu k \iff \frac ah=\frac bk \tag{4'}$$

---

### Question:

Neglecting the trivial cases that two vectors $\mathbf{v}=(v_x,v_y)$ and $\mathbf{w}=(w_x,w_y)$ are both $\mathbf{0}$, we suppose that they are both $\neq \mathbf{0}$. It is easy to try that
$$\mathbf{v}\bullet \mathbf{w}=v_xw_x+v_yw_y \tag 5$$ considering that $\theta$ is the convess angle

$$\mathbf{v}\bullet \mathbf{w}=vw\cos \theta, \quad \theta=\angle \mathbf{v}\mathbf{w} \tag 6$$

Now if $$\mathbf{v}\perp \mathbf{w} \iff \theta=\pi/2 \implies v_xw_x+v_yw_y=0 \iff (4)\tag 7$$

$$\mathbf{v}\parallel \mathbf{w} \iff \theta=0 \implies v_xw_x+v_yw_y=vw \tag 8$$

For the cross product $\times$

$$\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}=(v_xw_y-v_yw_x)\hat{\bf z}\equiv \mathbf{u}=(u_x,u_y) \tag 9$$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is perpendicular to the plane of lies $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, and $|\mathbf{u}|=|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}|=vw\sin \theta$.

Now if $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}=0\iff \theta=0,\pi$ is it true that

$$\mathbf{v}\parallel \mathbf{w} \iff v_xw_y-v_yw_x=0\quad \color{red}{?} \tag{10}$$

For my humble opinion it is true. Infact the $(10) \iff (3)$.

Using the cross product what is the condition that $$\mathbf{v}\perp \mathbf{w}, \quad ? \tag{11}$$

I have this simple problem:

> Assigned two vectors $\mathbf{v}=(4, k-2)$ and $\mathbf{w}=(k,6)$, you find for which $k\in \Bbb R$ values are parallel and perpendicular. The solution are $k=-4$ and $k=6$; and after $k=6/5$.

Using the $(8)$ (scalar product), I have

$$4k+6\left(k-2\right)=\sqrt{16+\left(k-2\right)^2}\cdot \sqrt{k^2+36}$$ that have only the solution $k=6$!!! and not also $k=-4$. Using the $(4)$ I have:

$$4k+6(k-2)=0 \iff k=6/5, \quad \text{ok!}$$

If from the $(9)$,

$$\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}=(v_xw_y-v_yw_x)\hat{\bf z}$$

I find $$v_xw_y-v_yw_x=0 \implies \mathbf{v}\parallel\mathbf{w}$$

[image]

> Hence, is it possible to find the condition of parallelism o perpendicularity using the cross vector, the $(9)$ and the $(11)$ that I not know? After is there a correlation between $(4')$ with the parallelism of the scalar product $(8)$ and cross product?

Comment: The reason you are missing the solution with $-4$ is that you don't consider the case when the angle is $\pi$, so $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w=-vw$

Comment: @Andrei Very good comment. I always done the case $\theta=0$! sigh.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @Andrei I have appreciated much it. Idem "welcome" for me. :-)

Comment: The condition that $\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{w}$, in terms of the cross product, is just that $\left|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right|=\left|\mathbf{v}\right|\left|\mathbf{w}\right|$ — that is to say, that the size of the cross product is as large as it can be.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you very much. It is absolutely true!

Comment: There is no cross product for vectors in the plane.

Comment: @egreg Hence I not can to use some condition? This morning I have find $\mathbf{v}\perp \mathbf{w}$ when $k=6/5$ using the cross vector but I not remember the steps. Thank you very much always.

Comment: @Sebastiano It's a wrong method. There is no canonical embedding of a plane in the three-dimensional space.

Comment: @egreg Any answer that clarifies my ideas better is always welcome.